# Race condition between resources when deploying CFN template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a template that sets up a stack with some Kinesis streams, a couple of Lambdas for subscribing and processing events from CloudWatch, etc.

Using [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CreateDestination.html) as a reference, I added the definition of a Destination to my template:

```
  LogDestination:
Properties:
  DestinationName:
    Ref: DestinationName
  DestinationPolicy:
    Fn::Sub:
      - |-
        {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "AWS": ["${AWS::AccountId}"]
                    },
                    "Action": "logs:PutSubscriptionFilter",
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:destination:${DestinationName}"
                }
            ]
        }
      - DestinationName:
          Ref: DestinationName
  RoleArn:
    Fn::GetAtt:
      - KinesisRole
      - Arn
  TargetArn:
    Fn::GetAtt:
      - LogStream
      - Arn
Type: AWS::Logs::Destination
```

Now, my problem:
When I attempt to deploy the entire template from scratch, it fails with status 400 ("Invalid Parameter") due to the Destination not being valid/existing.

However; it works if I deploy the stack without `LogDestination`, and then deploy `LogDestination` as a second change set.

So is it possible to have "race conditions" in CloudFormation? And if so; how can I go about resolving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Race conditions are possible in CloudFormation. [`DependsOn`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) can be used to explicitly order resource provisioning in the same stack operation ([`Ref`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html)/[`GetAtt`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html)/[`Sub`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) implicitly order resource provisioning as well)